# Недоступен открытый ключ для следующих ID ключей

Tags: debian, gpg, apt

При установке очередных обновлений возникает ошибка:

```
$ sudo apt update
Игн http://ftp.fr.debian.org stable InRelease
Получено:1 http://ftp.fr.debian.org stable Release.gpg [3 108 B]  
Получено:2 http://ftp.fr.debian.org stable Release [113 kB]                        
...
Получено:14 http://ftp.fr.debian.org stable/main Translation-ru [487 kB]                                         
Получено 13,3 MБ за 5с (2 365 kБ/c)                                                           
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей        
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
346 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Недоступен открытый ключ для следующих ID ключей:
EF0F382A1A7B6500
```

Эта же ошибка с английской локалью:

```
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
EF0F382A1A7B6500
```

Другой вид этой же ошибки:

```
W: GPG error: http://deb.example.com Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY KEY
```

Как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем случае такие ошибки исправляются одной командой:

```
apt-key adv --recv-keys  --keyserver keys.openpgp.org KEY-ID
```

Пример:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keys.openpgp.org EF0F382A1A7B6500
gpg: запрашиваю ключ 1A7B6500 с hkp сервера keys.gnupg.net
gpg: ключ 1A7B6500: импортирован открытый ключ "Debian Stable Release Key (9/stretch) <debian-release@lists.debian.org>"
gpg: Всего обработано: 1
gpg:                  импортировано: 1  (RSA: 1)
```

В конкретно этом случае проблему решило бы обновление пакета `debian-archive-keyring`.